# Estimating the value of $\sqrt{5}$ using Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, estimation

I'm trying to estimate the value of $\sqrt{5}$ using the Taylor Polynomial with the accuracy of $\frac{1}{10^3}$.

What I did was to calculate the third derivative of $\sqrt{x}$, which is $\frac{3}{8x^2\sqrt{x}}$. I calculate the third derivative, because I want accuracy on 3 digits.

Next I calculate the degree $n$ in Taylor polynomial for which I need to calculate to get the required accuracy: $|\frac{8x^2*\sqrt{x}}{3!}|\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{16x^2*\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{10^3} \Rightarrow n \geq 6 $.

So I have to calculate Taylor polynomial for $\sqrt{x+1}$ of degree $6$ and plug $4$ for $x$.

Am I doing it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: The Taylor polynomial around what center? $0$ isn’t going to work, but other centers will work, and require fewer terms.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Around center 4. So is it correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. What is your connection between number of digits and the order of the derivative?

Comment: @copper.hat So my use of the third derivative is correct but my reasoning is not? If so, could you please explain why we use the third derivative? I'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct: the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ converges  only for $|x|<1$.  But you can write
$$\sqrt 5=\sqrt{4\Bigl(1+\frac14\Bigr)}=2\sqrt{1+\frac14}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: So I should use the Taylor series of $2\sqrt{1+x}$? Just to be sure, I chose the wrong Taylor series, but the rest is correct? (Apart from my reasoning to use the third derivative..)

Comment: Probably there are other algorithms in special cases. But in this case it seems to be the simplest, all the more so as estimating the error in the binomial formula in this case is particularly simple (we obtain an alternating series).

Comment: You don't need the Taylor series to converge in order to use it for an estimate.

Comment: It is especially simple to estimate the error if you know the Taylor series, that's all I said.

Comment: Well, you said it is not correct and implied it is because $|x| \ge 1$.

Comment: I never said to use it for $x=4$!

Answer (score 2):

There are various approaches using Taylor series, rescaling as Bernard did, choice of expansion point, use of the mean value theorem for estimates, etc.

The following is based on the fact that the Taylor series for $x \mapsto \sqrt{x+k}$ is alternating (as Timur notes).

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{4+x}$. Note that the Taylor series converges for
$|x|<4$, and is alternating.

In particular, if $P_n$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$, then $f(x) < P_n(x)$ if $n$ is odd and $f(x) > P_n(x)$ if $n$
is even.

In particular, if $|P_{n+1}(x) -P_n(x)|  < \epsilon$, then 
$|f(x)-P_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

If we set $x=1$, then the first six terms of the Taylor expansion are
$2,{1 \over 4}, -{1 \over 64}, {1 \over 512}, -{5 \over 16384}$,$
{7 \over 131072}$ and since the last two terms differ
by less than ${1 \over 10^3}$ we see that
$|f(1)-P_4(1)| < {1 \over 10^3}$.

Hence $f(1) \approx P_4(1) = {36635 \over 16384} \approx 2.2360$, $\sqrt{5} \approx 2.2361$.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to center at values such as $x_0=4.84=2.2^2$, so that the error decays fast like the powers of $h=x-x_0=0.16$. Note that the series will be an alternating series, meaning that the error can be estimated by the first omitted term.